# NodeJS, http-proxy, socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-proxy

I am running a express web application on port 3030, but it is proxied through [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). The site works fine this way, but socket.io will not connect. It does recieve something as my console displays:

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 11319742841450363586
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/11319742841450363586
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 11319742841450363586
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
```

**app.js**

```
app.listen(3030)

io = require('socket.io')
socket = io.listen(app)

socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log('new connection')
})
```

**chat.js**

```
$(function() {
  console.log('connecting to chat...')
  var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.com:80')

  socket.on('connected',function(){
    console.log('connected')
  })
})
```

However, neither of the console.log statements ever display on the client or server side. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - Added http-proxy code**

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
  , proxyTable = {
      router: {
        'lou.mydomain.com': '127.0.0.1:3030'
      , 'foe.mydomain.com': '127.0.0.1:3000'
      // and some others
      }
    }
  , proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(proxyTable);

proxyServer.listen(80);
```

Comment: you should paste the code of your http-proxy configuration

Comment: @xsace - I edited the post to include http-proxy script

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Have you every figured it out?

Comment: Hmmm, can't remember...it was a problem client side with instantiating socket.io. Try different combinations of the io.connect options (port, domain, etc)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I knew, node-http-proxy doesn't work with WebSockets with Node > 0.6.x because of a bug (this was a couple of weeks ago). They said they were working on a fix, so it's possible that they didn't fix this yet. If you can't get that to work, try [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy).

Comment: For anyone else who's wondering, the issue alessioalex mentioned should have been fixed in socket.io 0.8.0: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/161

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you ask for socket.io on address 127.0.0.1:3030? And connecting to mydomain.com:3030, also.

If I understand right, you run express application on 3030 port, so that you need to connect there to in client-side JS.

```
$(function() {
    console.log('connecting to chat...')
    var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.com:3030');

    socket.on('connected',function(){
    console.log('connected')
    });
});
```

I guess...